# Fixed resolution?

Tags: html, web, resolution, fixed, blogger

I am in the process of designing a custom layout for my blogger site, and I have designed it to look the way that I see it on my computer so far. Recently I viewed it on another computer of different resolution and several of my DIVs were all over the place. This also happens when zooming in and out via ctrl+scroll wheel. Isn't there some type of code out there that allows you to lock your site at a certain resolution so everyone sees the DIVs in the spots they were meant to be in? This is really important to me, and I will appreciate any responses on how to solve this. Thank you!

Comment: Did you use absolute positions and set the width of these divs to a certain value by any chance? Some code would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Yes, all of my widths use "px" instead of percents.

Comment: yes, post some code please, then it is easy to help. Did you use position absolute or do you float the divs? Usually you just need a clean CSS and HTML to have it like you want - that's all, no other code needed ;)

Comment: I see, thats good news! :) Here's my basic div code: <style> 
.imageElement2 {
width:1020px; height:400px; overflow:auto;
position:absolute; z-index:2; left:50%; top:0%;
margin-left: -510px; margin-top:40px; text-align:center;
visibility:visible;}
</style>